# getParcelable returning null in app billing

Tags: android, null, parcelable

For some reason, buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT"); is returning null meaning my app ceases to function

Here is the relevant code:

```
String sku;
public void buyHint(){
    try {
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(),
                   sku, "inapp", "(id used here)");
        boolean buyintent=false;
        if(buyIntentBundle!=null){
            buyintent=true;
        }
        Log.d("buyintent"+buyintent,"daa");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");


        boolean buyintentparcel=false;
        if(buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT")!=null){
            buyintentparcel=true;
        }
        Log.d("buyparcel"+buyintentparcel,"da");
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                       1131, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));

        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So pretty much, using my various Log methods, I was able to determine that buyIntent bundle is not null, but buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT") is... any ideas

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: plz provide the code where you put Parcelable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");` can return `NULL` if there is no Google account logged in on your Android device.

Comment: I took your advice.  Tried to run it on my phone instead of an emulator, where I had my Google account logged in, and still received the same error.  So, it's got to be something different.  Any idea what else it could be?